# How to use Javamail API in Python?

Tags: python, jakarta-mail

I'm developing a Python code which sends email at certain intervals. The code will be running in a computer laboratory where Javamail is required in sending emails.

My Python code for sending mail failed with the error message below;

SMTPNotSupportedError: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.

However, a Matlab code works in sending email.

```matlab
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Server', ip_address);
setpref('Internet','E_mail','name@address.com');
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Username','name@address.com');
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Password','');
props = java.lang.System.getProperties;
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.auth','true');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.class', 'javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory');
props.remove('mail.smtp.socketFactory.class');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.starttls.enable', 'true' );
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.port','100’);
```

I wonder whether it is possible or not to use Javamail in Python?

Comment: In order for us to be able to try and help, please add what you have already tried in Python

Comment: Get rid of all the [socket factory properties](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  It sounds like your server doesn't support STARTTLS so you should try setting `mail.smtp.ssl.enable` to true instead.  If that doesn't work, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).